# mustache.js - can't get external template with jQuery get() method

Tags: jquery, mustache

I would like to include an external template in my main page with jQuery's get() method but I have an issue.

The following message is displayed in the Web browser's console :

> TypeError: Invalid template! Template should be a "string" but "undefined" was given as the first argument for mustache#render(template, view, partials) - (mustache.min.js:1:9011)

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body onload="myTemplate()">
    <div id="target">Loading ... </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.2.1/mustache.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="my-script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**templates.html**

```
<script id="tpl-1" type="text/html">
    <p>{{ name }} wins {{ calc }} points</p>
</script>
```

**my-script.js**

```
// my-script.js

function myTemplate() {

    $.get("tpl/templates.html", function(templates) {
        var template = $(templates).filter("#tpl-1").html();

        var data = {
            name: "Guy",
            calc: function () {
            return 8 + 2;
            }
        };

        var rendered = Mustache.render(template, data);
        $('#target').html(rendered);
    });
}
```

Nevertheless it works well with load() method :

```
// my-script.js

function myTemplate() {

    $("#target").load("tpl/templates.html #tpl-1", function() {
        var template = $("#tpl-1").html();

        var data = {
            name: "Guy",
            calc: function() {
                return 8 + 2;
            }
        };

        var rendered = Mustache.render(template, data);
        $('#target').html(rendered);
    });
}
```

Have you got an idea to run the get() method ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    function myTemplate() {

    $.get("templates.html", function(templates) {
        var template = $(templates).filter("#tpl-1").html();

        var data = {
            name: "Guy",
            calc: function () {
            return 8 + 2;
            }
        };

        var rendered = Mustache.render(template, data);
        $('#target').html(rendered);
    });
}

$('#target').on('load', myTemplate());

});
```